# iPhone Crash Log: Failed to Resume in Time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, debugging, ios4

I am looking at my crash logs and noticed "failed to resume in time"

```
Application Specific Information:
com.myApp.MyApp failed to resume in time 
elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 0.680 (user 0.350, system 0.330), 7% CPU 
elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.130, 1% CPU
```

How can I resume in time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that error means that you're doing something on the main thread that takes too long. The phone becomes unresponsive and the OS kills your app.

Try to use asynchronous APIs if possible, or run the long-running task in a background thread.

Comment: I am using async API's. Maybe I should kill my network connection when the app enters the background. Do you think that would resolve?