# ios Application crash : failed to resume in time

Tags: ios, crash

i am very new on iOS development. I have an issue , my app goes crash when app comes in foreground. I made a lot of search and found many solution but no one useful in my case. crash logs :

```
Aug 16 14:01:53 Sids-iPhone-2 ReportCrash[850] <Error>: Date/Time:       2013-08-16 

14:01:52.042 +0530
Aug 16 14:01:53 Sids-iPhone-2 ReportCrash[850] <Error>: OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Aug 16 14:01:53 Sids-iPhone-2 ReportCrash[850] <Error>: Report Version:  104
Aug 16 14:01:53 Sids-iPhone-2 ReportCrash[850] <Error>:  
��Aug 16 14:01:53 Sids-iPhone-2 ReportCrash[850] <Error>: Exception Type:  00000020
��Aug 16 14:01:53 Sids-iPhone-2 ReportCrash[850] <Error>: Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
��Aug 16 14:01:53 Sids-iPhone-2 ReportCrash[850] <Error>: Highlighted Thread:  0
Aug 16 14:01:53 Sids-iPhone-2 ReportCrash[850] <Error>:  
Aug 16 14:01:53 Sids-iPhone-2 ReportCrash[850] <Error>: Application Specific Information:
��Aug 16 14:01:53 Sids-iPhone-2 ReportCrash[850] <Error>: com.quytech.cakeboy failed to resume in time
��Aug 16 14:01:53 Sids-iPhone-2 ReportCrash[850] <Error>:  
��Aug 16 14:01:53 Sids-iPhone-2 ReportCrash[850] <Error>: Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 1.440 (user 1.440, system 0.000), 14% CPU 
��Aug 16 14:01:53 Sids-iPhone-2 ReportCrash[850] <Error>: Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.020, 0% CPU
��Aug 16 14:01:53 Sids-iPhone-2 ReportCrash[850] <Error>:  
��Aug 16 14:01:53 Sids-iPhone-2 ReportCrash[850] <Error>: Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
��Aug 16 14:01:53 Sids-iPhone-2 ReportCrash[850] <Error>: Thread 0:
��Aug 16 14:01:53 Sids-iPhone-2 ReportCrash[850] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
```

can anyone tell me about the proper reason of this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions on stackoverflow on this issue? For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359448/iphone-crash-log-failed-to-resume-in-time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358620/application-failed-to-resume-in-time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414467/failed-to-resume-in-time-on-resumption-from-background-crash

Comment: yes i  have tried all these link . but no one works.

Answer (score 3):

> 0x8badf00d: This code indicates that an application was terminated by
>   iOS because a watchdog timeout occurred. Basically, the application
>   took too long to launch, terminate, or respond to system events.

You're doing something that takes too long. Look at the backtrace and try to symbolicate it (convert from the hexidecimal addresses in the executable code to method names and line numbers) so that you can understand where the problem is. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports) thread should help you out there.

[Demystifying iOS App Crashes](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs) is a tutorial I found very useful.